# Anki giving duplicate warning for same word in different decks

Tags: anki

Anki is giving me a duplicate warning with a red background when I type "кофе" (the Russian word for "coffee") as a word because I have previously entered "кофе" in another deck as the Mongolian word for "coffee".

[image]

[image]

I like using the duplicate word warning system, because I'm getting vocabulary from multiple sources, and they may overlap with each other. Finding out that the Russian word for "coffee" is the same as the Mongolian word is kind of nice, but not vital.

The [documentation](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html) for Anki says

> When Anki checks for duplicates, it only compares other notes of the
>   same type. Thus if you add a capital city called “Orange” using the
>   capital city note type, you won’t see a duplicate message when it
>   comes time to learn how to say “orange” in French.

I suspect that Anki may think that my deck for Russian words is similar to my deck for Mongolian words, especially since I followed the instructions on [Loading Model Deck](https://fluent-forever.com/forums/topic/loading-model-deck/#.VGaHP4c-l4o) for how to set up two model decks for two languages (it's linked to from https://fluent-forever.com/gallery/)

How can I avoid a false alarm about the same word in decks about different languages?

This problem is mentioned in this [forum post on fluent forever](https://fluent-forever.com/forums/topic/loading-model-deck/), but no solution is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down, it offers to show duplicates:

[image]

If you choose to do so, it shows you them in the browser window of anki:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was "How can I avoid a false alarm about the same word in decks about different languages?"

Comment: @KitJohnson if I can show it's a false alarm, then it's no longer a problem.

Comment: Ah, I get it now.

Comment: @KitJohnson no worries.